# Cannot update because E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium

Tags: updates, ppa

I cannot update 5 packages because I get:

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]

Any clue?

The whole sequence:

**1) When I enter sudo apt-get update:**

> Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic
> InRelease Hit:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic
> InRelease
> Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
> Hit:5 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease
> Hit:6 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
> Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
> Hit:8 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
> Reading package lists... Done

**Then I enter sudo apt-get upgrade:**

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following
> packages have been kept back:   initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
> initramfs-tools-core linux-generic-hwe-18.04
> linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 The
> following packages will be upgraded:   chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra 1
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded. Need to
> get 1.117 kB of archives. After this operation, 5.120 B of additional
> disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  Ign:1
> http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64
> chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64
> chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] E: Failed to fetch
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] E: Unable to fetch some archives,
> maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

**So I try sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing**

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following
> packages have been kept back:   initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
> initramfs-tools-core linux-generic-hwe-18.04
> linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 The
> following packages will be upgraded:   chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra 1
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded. Need to
> get 1.117 kB of archives. After this operation, 5.120 B of additional
> disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  Ign:1
> http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64
> chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64
> chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] E: Failed to fetch
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_85.0.4183.121-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]

**UPDATE 1:**

Since the deb is not there, I manually downloaded and installed the newest version:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb

I had a warning telling me that a prvious version in the respository was a better idea because supported blah blah

I let Appcenter upgrade, and some were upgraded (GIMP fors instance) and other don't.

Now when I run sudo update & upgrade in terminal I get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following
> packages have been kept back:   initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
> initramfs-tools-core linux-generic-hwe-18.04
> linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 0
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

So Appcenter tells me to upgrade this packages but then it won't.

**UPDATE 2:**

Do not try this at home because I don't know exactly what I am doing, but following some ideas I read in other threads, I run sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y and all pending packages were installed but one. I run it again but no luck:

> The following packages have been kept back:   initramfs-tools-bin 0
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

My Wifi stopped working so I booted with the previous kernel version and remove the version I unintentionally upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Happy ending!
Two updates later, the Appcenter updated to the newest version of  initramfs-tools-bin. Now Everything is updated.

Problem (apparently) solved.